# Angular 9 report printing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, report, angular9

I have an Angular 9 application and I want to print reports.

**1.** What should I use for the report printing as when a user clicks on the print button a record should come from the database?

**2.** I do not want to use `window.print()` because it prints the screen and I did not want this, but also I want to show a preloader while a report record is being loaded.

As a back end development I am using .Net Core.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: You can suggest any npm for this or JavaScript library

Answer (score 3):

You have to deal it at back end side , make a method at your `backend` that would do the job for you . You can make use of  `database` there as per your need. You can make use of `ViewAsPDF` method.

Just writing desired code , make it useful accordingly

**Supposing** you have service and method that would do the `Database` related stuff

```
public IActionResult RDPReport()
        {
            var model = _reportService.GetRDPReport(); //it would fetch stuff from DB and return those things you want to view in your report

            var report = new ViewAsPdf("RDPReport")
            {
                PageMargins = { Left = 5, Bottom = 5, Right = 5, Top = 5 }, // Do as per need
                Model = model
            };
            return report;
        }
```

Comment: As your report record is concerned with database then perhaps it is good way .

Comment: Then what about crystal report??

Comment: Well , I've no idea about crystal reports . Once I did in this way that's why idea came up to share with you . If it is suitable for you you can go on else make a better choice

Comment: thinks broher for this